# A picture on the second tab makes the div not connect with the correct </div> endings. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML, CSS and Javascript code all together in one HTML document. The code gives me error as it is structure invalid. How can I close all elements properly and make it HTML5 valid. The following is the complete code of my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
       <head>
          <title>Empire Landscaping & hauling Inc.</title>
          <header>
             <h1>Empire landscaping & Hauling Inc.</h1>
             <h3>2001 South M-291 Highway</h3>
             <h3>Independence, Mo</h3>
          </header>
          <style type="text/css">
             #tabs ul {
             padding: 0px;
             margin: 20px;
             margin-left: 15px;
             list-style-type: none;
             }
             #tabs ul li {
             display: inline-block;
             clear: none;
             float: left;
             height: 30px;
             }
             #tabs ul li a {
             position: relative;
             margin-top: 16px;
             display: block;
             margin-left: 6px;
             line-height: 29px;
             padding-left: 10px;
             background: #CC0000;
             z-index: 9999;
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
             border-bottom: 0px;
             -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
             border-top-left-radius: 4px;
             -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
             border-top-right-radius: 4px;
             width: 130px;
             color: #FFFFFF;
             text-decoration: none;
             font-weight: bold;
             }
             #tabs ul li a:hover {
             text-decoration: underline;
             }
             #tabs #Content_Area {
             padding: 0 15px;
             clear:both;
             overflow:visible;
             line-height:19px;
             position: relative;
             top: 30px;
             z-index: 5;
             height: 200px;
             overflow: visible;
             }
             p { padding-left: 10px; }
          </style>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             function tab(tab) {
             document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('tab3').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('tab4').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('li_tab1').setAttribute("class", "");
             document.getElementById('li_tab2').setAttribute("class", "");
             document.getElementById('li_tab3').setAttribute("class", "");
             document.getElementById('li_tab4').setAttribute("class", "");
             document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
             document.getElementById('li_'+tab).setAttribute("class", "active");
             }
          </script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div
          <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
             <li id="li_tab1" onclick="tab('tab1')"><a>Decorative Rock</a></li>
             <li id="li_tab2" onclick="tab('tab2')"><a>Gravel</a></li>
             <li id="li_tab3" onclick="tab('tab3')"><a>Mulch</a></li>
             <li id="li_tab4" onclick="tab('tab4')"><a>Topsoil and Fill</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="Content_Area">
          <div id="tab1">
             <p>Empire carries many types of decorative rock for your lawn care needs!          </br>
                We carry decorative rocks that will help style your yard and make it look      wonderful.</br>
                This is our Colorado River Rock, one of our most popular materials that we    sell.</br>
                This rock complements dark homes and surroundings.
             </p>
             <p> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?      q=tbn:ANd9GcQSAFchzIyxH2UJjno-aIekETSFJr-wko1wdWsxeAZInv8VDq1g"        style="width:250px;height:270px;"/></p>
             Next is our Ozark River Rock. This type of rock can add a gentle warmth to   your yard.</br>
             Ozark has a rich, warm color and because of this red is always a winning          combination.</p>
             <p> <img src="http://iowalandscapesupply.com/wp-  content/uploads/2012/10/pink-granite.jpg" style="width:250px;height:270px;"/>    </p>
             <p>A special type of rock that we have is the Lava Rock.</br>
                We carry this rock in the color of red and various shades of black, so it        complements light homes and surroundings.
             </p>
             <p> <img    src="http://www.hollowtrucking.com/images/exotic_landscaping_stones/Red_Lava_Rock.jpg" style="width:250px;height:270px;"/></p>
          </div>
          <div id="tab2">
             We carry limestone gravel in several different sizes. We also carry dust and    crusher run.</br></p>
          </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this also has for the coding of tabs 3 and 4, <div id="tab3"> , and <div id="tab4">

Comment: lots of spaces in your img src attributes

Comment: Under `body` you have `<div` which is not properly closed

Comment: can you recreate the issue in https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m5rv7hcz/1/

Comment: oops, I flagged it as spam, realised it's just a formatting error - sorry

Comment: Your entire HTML structure is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

start div not close under body first div

```
<body>
<div 

<div id="tabs">
```

replace to

```
<body>
    <div> 

    <div id="tabs">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire HTML code structure is invalid and I restructure and this should solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         #tabs ul {
         padding: 0px;
         margin: 20px;
         margin-left: 15px;
         list-style-type: none;
         }
         #tabs ul li {
         display: inline-block;
         clear: none;
         float: left;
         height: 30px;
         }
         #tabs ul li a {
         position: relative;
         margin-top: 16px;
         display: block;
         margin-left: 6px;
         line-height: 29px;
         padding-left: 10px;
         background: #CC0000;
         z-index: 9999;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         border-bottom: 0px;
         -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
         border-top-left-radius: 4px;
         -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
         border-top-right-radius: 4px;
         width: 130px;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-weight: bold;
         }
         #tabs ul li a:hover {
         text-decoration: underline;
         }
         #tabs #Content_Area {
         padding: 0 15px;
         clear:both;
         overflow:visible;
         line-height:19px;
         position: relative;
         top: 30px;
         z-index: 5;
         height: 200px;
         overflow: visible;
         }
         p { padding-left: 10px; }
      </style>
      <title>Empire Landscaping & hauling Inc.</title>
   </head>
   <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
      <header>
         <h1>Empire landscaping & Hauling Inc.</h1>
         <h3>2001 South M-291 Highway</h3>
         <h3>Independence, Mo</h3>
      </header>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function tab(tab) {
           document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('tab3').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('tab4').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('li_tab1').setAttribute("class", "");
           document.getElementById('li_tab2').setAttribute("class", "");
           document.getElementById('li_tab3').setAttribute("class", "");
           document.getElementById('li_tab4').setAttribute("class", "");
           document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
           document.getElementById('li_'+tab).setAttribute("class", "active");
         }
      </script>
      <div id="tabs">
         <ul>
            <li id="li_tab1" onclick="tab('tab1')"><a>Decorative Rock</a></li>
            <li id="li_tab2" onclick="tab('tab2')"><a>Gravel</a></li>
            <li id="li_tab3" onclick="tab('tab3')"><a>Mulch</a></li>
            <li id="li_tab4" onclick="tab('tab4')"><a>Topsoil and Fill</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="Content_Area">
            <div id="tab1">
               <p>Empire carries many types of decorative rock for your lawn care needs!          <br/>
                  We carry decorative rocks that will help style your yard and make it look      wonderful.<br/>
                  This is our Colorado River Rock, one of our most popular materials that we    sell.<br/>
                  This rock complements dark homes and surroundings.
               </p>
               <p> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?      q=tbn:ANd9GcQSAFchzIyxH2UJjno-aIekETSFJr-wko1wdWsxeAZInv8VDq1g"        style="width:250px;height:270px;"/></p>
               <p>
                  Next is our Ozark River Rock. This type of rock can add a gentle warmth to   your yard.<br/>
                  Ozark has a rich, warm color and because of this red is always a winning          combination.
               </p>
               <p> <img src="http://iowalandscapesupply.com/wp-  content/uploads/2012/10/pink-granite.jpg" style="width:250px;height:270px;"/>    </p>
               <p>A special type of rock that we have is the Lava Rock.<br/>
                  We carry this rock in the color of red and various shades of black, so it        complements light homes and surroundings.
               </p>
               <p> <img    src="http://www.hollowtrucking.com/images/exotic_landscaping_stones/Red_Lava_Rock.jpg" style="width:250px;height:270px;"/></p>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2">
               <p>We carry limestone gravel in several different sizes. We also carry dust and    crusher run.<br/></p>
            </div>
            this is the first tab i can add pictures here and it doesn't affect anything
            The kind of Mulch that we carry is fine shredded. We have several different colors.
            Our topsoil is pulverized with compost, along with our fill dirt which is chunky, and sandy.
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```